# When i try to insert into the table which blob data type I am getting an error

Tags: oracle, blob, sql-insert

```
Create TABLE long_claw
(
    "name" varchar2(10),
    phno number(10),
    clg_docs blob
)
partition by hash(phno);

insert into pepe.long_claw("name",phno,clg_docs)
values('Satyajit',9176788770,to_lob('ceb'));
```

When I tried to execute the insert statement I got the following error:

> Error starting at line : 9 in command -
>
> ```
> insert into pepe.long_claw("name",phno,clg_docs)
> values('Satyajit',9176788770,to_lob('ceb'))
> ```
>
> Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 30
>
> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

I need some help here.

Comment: Please format code and error message as code. Furthermore, as long as you don't tell which database software you are using, we probably can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_LOB` converts `LONG` or `LONG RAW` values  to `LOB` values. So you cannot directly use a string to convert it to `LOB` . Instead use `hextoraw()`  OR `utl_raw.cast_to_raw()`

```
INSERT INTO long_claw("name",phno,clg_docs)
VALUES('Satyajit',9176788770,hextoraw('ceb'));


INSERT  INTO  long_claw("name",phno,clg_docs)
VALUES('Satyajit',9176788770,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('ceb'));
```

Answer (score -1):

you need create `procedure`

```
create or replace procedure proc_name(na in varchar2, ph in number, clg_doc in blob)
begin 
inser into pepe.long_claw("name",phno,clg_docs) values 
(na, ph, clg_doc);
end;
```

and call it procedure